# That time of the year again

Tags: discussion

```
              +
              !
            * O *             Frohe Weihnachten
          .   *   .
          I * ! * I           und ein
          * O * O *
        .   * I *   .         Gutes Neues Jahr.
        I *   *   * I
        *   * O *   *
      * O *   *   * O *
    .   *   * O *   *   .
    I *   *   *   *   * I
.   * O *   * O *   * O *   .
I *   * I *   *   * I *   * I
* O *   * * * H * * *   * O *
  * * *   =========   * * *
```

- Merry Christmas
- Joyeux Noël
- Щасливого Різдва!

to all of you.

---

P.S.: That drawing is kinda historic. Created ca. 1984 for the default screen of a mainframe system. It replaced the standard screen(*1) during the holidays starting at the last regular full workday until first work day after New Year  (*2).

On a regular terminal candles (`I`) and baubles (`O`) were full intensity with the flames (`.`) blinking while the tree was reduced intensity. On one of the few colour terminal the baubles were red, the candles yellow and the tree green (*3).

---

*1 - Usually just system name in large letters made from letters.

*2 - German holidays are a bit more complex - and even more for a single system used in 30+ countries worldwide :)) This year and in Germany it would have been from the morning of the 22nd until evening of the 2nd.

*3 - if configured right:))

Comment: I hope everybody put the blinkenlights on the Christmas tree!